# git pre-commit: modify files in pre-commit script

Tags: git, githooks

Is it possible to modify changed files(I want to tidy up xmls) in git pre-commit hook script? If yes, how to do it? Now I have such script:

```
files=`git diff --name-only --cached`


was_xml=false
for file in $files
do
    extension="${file##*.}"
    xml="xml"
    if [ "$extension" = "$xml" ]
    then
        tmp_file=$file"_xmlint"
        echo $tmp_file >> fuck
        xmllint --format --encode utf8 $file > $tmp_file
        rm $file
        mv $tmp_file $file
        git add $file
        was_xml=true
    fi
done

if $was_xml ; then
    git commit -m 'Xml cleanup'
fi
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look up `clean` and `smudge` ( see http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html ).  You could do XML reformatting during the clean phase of staging a file.

Comment: Oh, thanks! But how can I get git filename from clean filter script? I've tried to use %1(I'm writing on bash), but it doesn't work.

Comment: The clean filter gets called with the file contents on stdin, and it puts the filtered result on stdout.  It doesn't get the filename of the file it happens to be working on _but_ using .gitattributes, you control exactly which files for which it will be run.  For instance, if you named your reformatting filter ``indent-xml``, you could add the following line to the appropriate .gitattributes file: ``*.xml filter=indent-xml``.  Then it would get run for all and only your xml files.